# XML not rendering value for 1 action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, curl

I am working on an API in rails that will respond to xml and json. On all but 1 action xml and json both respond as expected. On the total_words action it responds correctly with json but not xml.

pages_controller.rb

```
class Api::PagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
    respond_with @pages
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @page
  end

  def total_words
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @page.words
  end
end
```

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :published_on, :title

  validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :content, :presence => true


  def words
    self.content.split.size
  end

end
```

route.rb

```
API::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'api/pages/:id/total_words' => 'api/pages#total_words', :as => "total_word_api_page"

  namespace :api do
    resources :pages
  end

end
```

If I access via curl using:

```
curl --url http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/pages/3/total_words.xml
```

I get nothing.

If I access via curl using:

```
curl --url http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/pages/3/total_words.json
```

I get: 3

If I access via the browser using:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/pages/3/total_words.xml
```

I get:

```
Template is missing

Missing template api/pages/total_words, application/total_words with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/api_test/API/app/views"
```

If I did the same in the browser but using json I would get: 3 just like I did in curl.

I'm not sure why json and xml and responding differently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that I was trying to return an integer or string which worked with json but not xml. I modified the return to a hash and the json successfully returned the correct value using both json and xml. It looks like xml is ok with arrays or hashes.

My modified method is now:

```
  def words
    { id: self.id, word_count: self.content.split.size }
  end
```